# Rails, calling model method in another model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have a model method that translates a country_code field into the full country name:

```
def country_name
    country = ISO3166::Country[country_code]
    country.translations[I18n.locale.to_s] || country.name
end
```

I want to then define another method in the same model that searches on the full country name field. But, I have to use the country_name defined in the above model method. How do I go about calling this method?

I have my attempt below, but that doesn't seem to work... thanks so much in advance!

```
def self.search(query)
   where("summary ILIKE ? OR country_name ILIKE ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
end
```

Comment: First you need to clarify how do you pass instance method `country_name` to static method `search`. do you instantiate it first could you please show us. and do you get any error messages?

Comment: Hi Moustafa - right now, the error is simply "PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "country_name" does not exist" which makes sense considering it is not a column in my model. I'm just confused if I should be passing, or creating a new column.. or something else? Thanks

Comment: What column is in your model that identifies the country?  is it country_code or country_name?

Comment: right you should be querying the column name that holds the country full name in your database table. also you should adjust the SQL query to be `LIKE` instead of `ILIKE`

Comment: hmm - that's the problem. there is no column name that holds the country full name. I only store the country code in country_code. Is there a way to convert the code to full name in the search method?

Comment: If the country_code is already given in your code earlier, why don't you just search directly for the code?

Comment: it's for a user query - i want the user to able to search for the full country name vs. not all people know the country codes for each country.

Comment: So what you need is a method that converts name to code, so then you can take the user inputted name, convert it to the country_code, then use that in your search query.

Comment: i was thinking to convert the country code to name, then use the name as the item to match against the user inputted query. is this not possible?